# User setting background image

Tags: uiimageview, background-image

Within my IOS application I would like to allow users to set their own background image. They pick an image from their photo library and then they set it as the background of the application. There is an example of this within the "Weather Channel" application. What code do I need to do to implement this?

Comment: You need to try something first and then ask specific questions about specific problems.

Comment: Can't try if I don't know how :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) and [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html)to capture the image. Many tutorials are available to explain how to do this. Once you have the `UIImage`, you can set up a `UIImageView` that covers the background of your app.